# index.html from create-react-app build doesn't work in web browser

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app`.
The react application works well by `npm start`.
But...
I ran `npm run build` then index.html and main...js/main...css were create in build directory.
And moved this files into tomcat web application's home directory.
When I open the index.html in the browser, blank screen only shown.
What's the problem ?
(I added "homepage" : "." into package.json, so this isn't 404 problem)